# Confused source with destination with ddrescue

Tags: raid, data-recovery, ddrescue

I was about to recover second out of five failing RAID disks with ddrescue, and sudden peculiar twist occurred in my mind, and I typed

```
sudo ddrescue --verbose --idirect --no-scrape -f /dev/sda /dev/sdc disk1.logfile
```

while there should've been /dev/sdc /dev/sda. This ran for about 28 seconds:

```
GNU ddrescue 1.23
About to copy 6001 GBytes from '/dev/sda' to '/dev/sdc'
    Starting positions: infile = 0 B, outfile = 0 B
    Copy block size: 128 sectors Initial skip size: 117248 sectors
Sector size: 512 Bytes

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos: 5961 MB, non-trimmed: 0 B, current rate: 59375 kB/s
     opos: 5961 MB, non-scraped: 0 B, average rate: 205 MB/s
non-tried: 5995 GB, bad-sector: 0 B, error rate: 0 B/s
  rescued: 5961 MB, bad areas: 0, run time: 28s
pct rescued: 0.09%, read errors: 0, remaining time: 8h 6m
                              time since last successful read: n/a
Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (forwards)^C
  Interrupted by user
```

Is there any way to undo the action, would created map file help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have copied the initial 5961 MB of `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdc`, overwriting whatever data was in the first 5961 MB of `/dev/sdc`.

There is no way to simply undo. The mapfile can only tell you the exact size of the overwritten fragment.

Depending on the type of the RAID and the layout of files and/or filesystem(s) involved, you might be able to rescue some files or even whole filesystems from `/dev/sdc` with tools like `testdisk` or `photorec`. Depending on the type of the RAID you might need to forcefully re-assemble the RAID in some read-only mode that ignores the fact your `/dev/sdc` probably does not look like a member of RAID now; or maybe you could re-assemble the RAID "by hand" with a low-level tool like `dmsetup`.

Do not expect wonders. Writing almost 6 GB of "random" data to the beginning of any disk is almost certainly a death blow to filesystem(s) that exist there. In your case some data is lost, it has been overwritten, it's simply no longer there. You will be lucky if you recover anything.

In an *extremely* lucky situation the beginning of your `/dev/sdc` is responsible for holding sectors not used by any filesystem, or blocks marked free in some filesystem (these are possible because of RAID; in a non-RAID setup the beginning of a disk is always important). So *maybe* your mishap was harmless. *This is a wonder you should not expect though.*

Filesystems (if any) that fully exist *beyond* the overwritten part are unaffected by your mishap and recovering them might be as "simple" as finding their signatures and building a partition table that will make them visible to the OS (this is what `testdisk` can do); or might not. Or *maybe* the partition table is on another disk and you will see it once you re-assemble the RAID (which by itself may or may not be easy). Without detailed information about the RAID and the data structures (partitions, filesystems) within, I cannot tell if there's even a chance for you to be that lucky. Note in some multi-device setups (like LVM) it's not immediately clear which (parts of which) filesystems belong to which (parts of which) disks.

I wrote "might" and "could" because the above is for rescuing from a physically healthy disk that holds logically corrupted data.

If you suspect or you know that `/dev/sdc` is failing physically, i.e. the disk *itself* is not healthy (as opposed to a logical failure where some (meta)data is corrupt, something that you just caused anyway), you should `ddrescue` the drive in the right direction and work with the copy. So basically you should do what you were going to do, and then use a copy to overcome the logical corruption: the one that possibly was before plus the one that may result from reading from the physically unhealthy source, plus the one you caused by overwriting a part of the source with something else.

Since RAID means *Redundant* Array of Independent Disks, *maybe* you can rebuild the RAID from other members and you don't (and didn't) need `/dev/sdc` in the first place. This obviously depends on the RAID.

The phrase "second out of five failing RAID disks" is vague, I don't really know:

- if you mean "failing RAID", possibly logically failing,
- or if you mean "failing disks", possibly physically failing,
- and if so, then "five failing" out of how many;
- what type of RAID it's about;

so I cannot really tell if you can recover from your mishap thanks to other members of the RAID.

In general some data is lost. The fact RAID is involved may allow some approaches that increase chances of (partial or full) recovery; and it may disallow some other approaches. Without detailed information about the RAID and the data structures (partitions, filesystems) within, there is no way to optimally guide you at this point; there are too many ifs and too many "entry points" for luck. If you want further help then ask a new question where you should give us detailed information about the RAID. Do not expect wonders even then.

Comment: This is absolutely correct but sugar coated.  The answer really should start "very unlikely and data WILL be lost but there is a sliver of hope of maybe recovering some data if you are lucky.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: @davidgo The questions are "is there any way to undo the action? would created map file help?". My answer starts by answering these. The later part is something extra, an answer to implicit "how can I recover the data?". What you wrote may be an improvement to this part, but IMO the answer shall not start with it. The start is for answering the explicit questions. Your comment is right in its gist though, thanks; I'm going to add vinegar to the later part.

Comment: Kamil, thank you, your answer made me rephrase my question slightly: https://superuser.com/questions/1816823/recovering-qnap-ts-559pro-raid-5-after-double-disk-failure